# jQuery Selector for ID ends with <blablabla> and nothing after that

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know the selector for an ID that ends with a word e.g `$("[id$='txtTitle']")`
but how do I ensure nothing comes after `txtTitle`? E.g how do I ensure `txtTitle1` doesn't match?

Comment: The `$=` comparison means "ends with". The string "txtTitle1" does not end with "txtTitle". You can verify that with an extremely simple test.

Comment: How would it *end with* `txtTitle` if something comes after?!

Comment: The ends-with selector `$` means just that - - the attribute value must ***end*** with your text. So if more text comes after what you've entered, then the attribute doesn't end-with that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using jQuery, however, it can be verified pretty easily with this native code:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[id$='txtTitle']"));
```

```html
<div id="footxtTitle">Partial match</div>
<div id="txtTitle">Full match</div>
<div id="txtTitle1">No match</div>
```